# Groups - Prove that G is generated by A and B

Tags: group-theory

I'm revising for an Algebra exam and I am stuck on this question:

Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes and not necessarily distinct. Suppose that $A \ne B$ are subgroups of $G$ with $1<|A|$ and $1<|B|$. Prove that $G$ is generated by $A$ and $B$.

I am familiar with Lagrange's Theorem but I am unsure how to apply it here.

Thanks!

Comment: Since $A \neq B$ is the only condition, what happens when $|A| = |B|$? For example, in $G=S_3$, we have $A = \{e, (12)\}, B = \{e, (1,3)\}$. $A, B$ together generate $G$ but it is not straightforward conclusion.

Comment: Take a non abelian group $G$ of order 39. This will have 12 subgroups of order 3. No two of these can generate $G$. Hence we need the assumption that $|A| = p, |B|=q$. In this case $|AB| = \frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap B|} = pq$ since $|A\cap B| = 1$ and hence $AB = G$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Use Lagrange's Theorem and the fact that if a group has prime order, then it is [cyclic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicGroup.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$, then by Lagrange theorem, the cardinality of $A$ and $B$ each divides $pq$. If either one group has cardinality $pq$, then the statement holds trivially.

Therefore we may assume that $|A| = p$ and $|B|=q$. And from the hint by Jose, we may let $A$ and $B$ be generated by elements say $a$ and $b$ since they are cyclic.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I must have gaps in my knowledge. I assume you can infer something since A and B can be generated by a single element respectively?